# MUI Autocomplete multiple freesolo; how to get new values?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm implementing a generic autocomplete that will allow users to select multiple items, either from a list or by typing a new value, similar to how recipients are managed in email. Everything is functioning, I can add items to the list (including new items), remove, etc. See below.

What I want to do is identify when an item is new (not already in the list), so I can take other actions (for example to show a dialog so that user can add some other associated details). I suppose I can compare the list before and after a change, figure out which item is new, and see if it's already in my list of options, but that seems cumbersome.

Any suggestions on how best to do this?[image: Screenshot of existing autocomplete field]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, thought I'd post this in case anyone else has the same question.

The OnChange event has an optional parameter titled 'reason'; the value will be either removeOption (when deleting), selectOption (selecting an existing item from the list), or createOption (adding a new item).

Problem solved!